# Different results when using calculated column and measure in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, calculated-columns, measure

I created a calculated column and measure. They should bring same result. But when creating visuals I get different view.

My calculated column:

[image]

```
if [CostPrice] = null then 0 else [AmountWithDiscount] - [CostPrice]
```

And visual with this column:

[image][image]

When I try to do the same thing with measure it turns out differently.
My measure:

```
_surcharge = IF(SUM(CheckLines[CostPrice])= BLANK(), 0, SUM(CheckLines[AmountWithDiscount]) - SUM(CheckLines[CostPrice]))
```

Visual with this measure:

[image] [image]

It seems to me that logically these two visuals should be the same.

Comment: That's why they are different :) If both returns the same, no worth of having 2 different terms Measures and Calculated Column, right? Get some details in the below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculated column is evaluated and calculated for each row, while the measure is evaluated once for all the rows that are in the context.

This is an important difference that might explain the different numbers that you are getting:

- The calculated column "SurchargeColumn" is calculated for each row and has the value 0 if the "CostPrice" equals NULL. Then the values of this column are summed up and shown on the first visual.
- The measure will sum all the values of the "CostPrice" at once. In case the result is blank then it will return 0, otherwise it will return sum of "AmountWithDiscount" minus the sum of "CostPrice". In the measure calculation it doesn't matter if the CostPrice on the individual row is NULL or not; also the rows with CostPrice=NULL are taken into account.

Comment: Thank you. I am beginner in PowerBI so it was difficult to understand :)